How do I connect two processes, on running on a docker container through a socket?
I've been working on this issue for a few days now and I've found nothing on my specific issue, when I run the two processes on the host it works fine, but even though I have the correct port open on the container I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/test.py", line 14, in 
data = receive_data()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/test.py", line 8, in receive_data
s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I ran the command below to create a docker container running with ports 1234 and 8888 (for jupyter notebook) open (Jupyter works fine btw)

docker run -d -it --name tensorflow --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/Control,target=/app -p 127.0.0.1:8888:8888 -p 127.0.0.1:1234:1234 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-jupyter

I have a lua program running outside the container sending a known data stream to localhost on port 1234.
local socket = require("socket")
local host = "localhost"
local port = 1234
local server = assert(socket.bind(host, port))
server:settimeout(0)

local function sendData(data)
    local client = server:accept()
    if client then
        client:send(data .. "\n")
        client:close()
    end
end

I then have a test python program try to pick it up, on the main host it works fine, in the container not so much.
import socket

host = "localhost"
port = 1234
def receive_data():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, port))
        data = s.recv(1024).decode()
        if data:
            return data.split(',')


Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  In particular, what host and port are the client program calling, and is the client running in its own container or somewhere else?  You should not need do disable Docker's networking layer with --network host.

@DavidMaze Since asking this question I've been trying several different things, mainly switching ports to try and fix the issue. I eventually figured out that --network host just breaks networking for me completely, I've even tried running it through port 8888 which I know works since Jupyter is running on it, in that case though instead of giving the traceback error it just hangs.

The container program can't connect to localhost, because that means "the current container", but see From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?  The server process may need to listen on 0.0.0.0 ("all interfaces") and not localhost, depending on your specific Docker setup.

@DavidMaze I was about to test your idea when my computer decided to change the rules on me, I restarted my computer to fix a different issue and now while the lua script is running the container refuses to start and while the container is running the lua script refuses to run both saying the same thing, the port is in use. I mean yeah, it's how you talk to each other. I'm convinced my PC is haunted now and my attempts at networking has angered the spirit.
